# Window dragging issue for webos

Tags: typescript

You can drag a window perfectly fine with only one window open, but as soon as you open another, the window is offset from the mouse on the y axis by sum of the height of every window open.

I expected for it to handle multiple windows. But one of the window's is buggy while the other works prefectly fine.

`
import { App } from './types';

```
// Define a class for window location data
class WindowLocation {
  left: number = 0;
  top: number = 0;
}

interface WindowOptions {
  title: string;
  icon: SVGElement;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}

class DraggableWindow {
  // private windowLocations: Map<string, WindowLocation> = new Map();
  private isDragging: boolean = false;
  private offsetX: number = 0;
  private offsetY: number = 0;
  
  constructor(app: App, private windowDiv: HTMLElement, private titleDiv: HTMLElement) {
    console.log('called')
    titleDiv.style.cursor = 'grab';

    titleDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      console.log(this.offsetY)
      this.isDragging = true;
      const rect = windowDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.offsetX = e.clientX - rect.left;
      this.offsetY = e.clientY - rect.top;
    });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      if (this.isDragging) {
        const newLeft = e.clientX - this.offsetX;
        const newTop = e.clientY - this.offsetY;

        this.windowDiv.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
        this.windowDiv.style.top = newTop + 'px';
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      this.isDragging = false;
    });
  }
}

class WindowManager {
  private windows: Map<string, HTMLElement> = new Map();
  // private windowLocations: Map<string, WindowLocation> = new Map();

  createWindow(app: App, options: WindowOptions) {
    const windowDiv = this.generateWindowHTML(app, options);
    this.windows.set(app.meta.pkg, windowDiv);

    // Initialize window location data
    // this.windowLocations.set(app.meta.pkg, new WindowLocation());

    // Add event listeners for window interactions (e.g., minimize, maximize, close)
    // For example, you can add drag events here for window dragging.

    document.body.appendChild(windowDiv);
  }

  closeWindow(pkg: string) {
    const window = this.windows.get(pkg);
    if (window) {
      window.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  openWindow(pkg: string, data?: any) {
    const window = this.windows.get(pkg);
    if (window) {
      // Show the window and handle data
      window.style.display = 'block';

      // Handle data and interactions
      // ...

      // You can also use this.windowLocations.get(pkg) to retrieve window location data
    }
  }

  private generateWindowHTML(app: App, options: WindowOptions): HTMLElement {
    const windowDiv = document.createElement('div');
    windowDiv.classList.add('w-96', 'h-64', 'text-white', 'shadow-md', 'm-4', 'bg-[#5271FF]', 'rounded-lg', 'relative');

    // Create the window's HTML structure using the provided options (title, icon, width, height)
    // You can include the description in the window content if needed.

    // Set window title
    const titleDiv = document.createElement('div');
    titleDiv.textContent = options.title;
    windowDiv.appendChild(titleDiv);

    // Make the title bar draggable for window dragging
    new DraggableWindow(app, windowDiv, titleDiv);

    return windowDiv;
  }

}

// Initialize the WindowManager
export const windowManager = new WindowManager();
```

`

Live demo:
https://02e3-108-217-212-32.ngrok-free.app/

Try the windows thing to see what im talking about